# How to install packages into gluon.contrib with web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I want to install jsonpickle into web2py (mac osx yosemite, most recent version of web2py). I did:

```
cd /Applications/web2py/Contents/Resources/gluon/contrib
pip install jsonpickle -t .
```

And it seemed to install nicely into that directory. However, in my module, I tried `from gluon.contrib import jsonpickle`, but it gave me an `ImportError: No module named jsonpickle`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out: had to move jsonpickle to the site-packages folder instead of gluon/contrib, and then it imported fine.